# For a particle experiencing a diagonal force in an electric field, why can't you separate the force into vertical and horizontal components?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, electric-fields, charge

In class, we're learning about how to calculate the resultant force acting on an electron due to other electrons. Here's an example question.
[image]

My approach to this question was to separate the horizontal forces acting on the -1.0 nC particle from the vertical forces. This would be done by using the horizontal distance and vertical distance to the positive charge instead of using the actual distance to that particle. I would then add the horizontal forces together and then use Pythagoras's theorem with the vertical force to calculate the resultant diagonal force.

This didn't come out to be the correct value the teacher got. The correct method was to find the diagonal distance to calculate the diagonal force. Then to separate the vertical and horizontal components and then continue from there.

I explained my thought process to my teacher and I didn't feel convinced at all by my teacher's answer to why you couldn't find the horizontal and vertical components without finding the direct distance to that positive charge. Is there a particular reason as to why my method doesn't work or any topics I can search up for myself to learn more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method finds the force that the $-1nC$ charge would experience if there was a $+1nC$ charge directly above  it (0.17m away) and a $+1nC$ charge on the left (0.22m) away.

It's larger than the real force as the distances are smaller and there are two charges instead of one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector $\mathbf F$ whose magnitude is $F$ and whose direction from the horizontal axis is $\theta$, the horizonal and vertical components of this force are given respectively by

$$F_x=F\cos\theta$$
$$F_y=F\sin\theta$$

The magnitude of the electrostatic force between two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ separated by a distance $r$ is given by

$$F=\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}$$

where $k$ is a constant, and the direction points along the line going from one charge to the other.

Therefore, the horizonal and vertical components of the electrostatic force are given respectively by

$$F_x=\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}\cos\theta$$
$$F_y=\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}\sin\theta$$

Notice how we still have $r$ in the denominators here.

If you really did want to include the horizontal and vertical distances $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ while eliminating $r$ you certainly can:

$$F_x=\frac{kq_1q_2}{x^2}\cos^3\theta$$
$$F_y=\frac{kq_1q_2}{y^2}\sin^3\theta$$

but notice that this is not the same thing that you propose of

$$F_x=\frac{kq_1q_2}{x^2}$$
$$F_y=\frac{kq_1q_2}{y^2}$$

which is incorrect.